# How to print multiple binomial test result from a function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, return, binomial-coefficients

I have made a function to do binomial test in R. I have successfully run it without using loop (for i statement). However, I have been trying to simplify it by applying for i statement, but only work halfway of What I want. My function is:

```
binom_test_2b = function(spot_id, cluster_id, marker_gene){
# Finding the cluster and marker gene in scRNA-seq dataset
cluster_id  = sample(as.data.frame(Idents(glioblastoma))[,1], 1)
marker = FindMarkers(glioblastoma, ident.1 = cluster_id)
marker = cbind(gene = rownames(marker), marker)
rownames(marker) = 1:nrow(marker) 

# Finding the cluster and the spot in spatial dataset
cluster = Idents(glio_spatial)
df_cluster = as.data.frame(cluster)
df_cluster = cbind(spot_id = rownames(df_cluster), df_cluster)
rownames(df_cluster) = 1:nrow(df_cluster)
df_cluster = df_cluster[df_cluster$cluster == sample(df_cluster[,ncol(df_cluster)],1),]
spot_id = sample(df_cluster[,1],1)
spatial_count = as.data.frame(glio_spatial@assays$Spatial@counts)
spatial_count = cbind(gene = rownames(spatial_count), spatial_count)
rownames(spatial_count) = 1:nrow(spatial_count) 
spatial_count = spatial_count[c("gene", spot_id)]
spatial_count = rename(spatial_count, "count" = spot_id)

#Finding the percentage of the marker gene expressed in the spot
# List of genes with not zero count at the chosen spot
gene_spot  = spatial_count[spatial_count$count != 0,]

#Finding gene intersection between scRNA-seq cluster and spot
intersection = inner_join(gene_spot, marker)

#Finding marker_gene sample
marker_gene = sample(head(intersection[order(intersection[2], decreasing = TRUE),],5)[,1],5)

for (i in 1:length(marker_gene)){
    ratio_spot = gene_spot[which(gene_spot$gene == marker_gene[i]), ][,2]/sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])
    #Finding the percentage of the marker gene expressed outside the cluster
    all_cells_one_gene = glioblastoma@assays$RNA@counts[marker_gene[i],]
    selected_cells_one_gene = all_cells_one_gene[cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]
    gene_count_out_cluster = glioblastoma@assays$RNA@counts[,cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]
    ratio_out_cluster = sum(selected_cells_one_gene)/sum(gene_count_out_cluster)
    result_1 = sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for scRNA-seq cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s.", marker_gene, cluster_id, spot_id)
    result_2 = binom.test(as.integer(ratio_spot*sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])), as.integer(sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])), as.integer(ratio_out_cluster))
}
return(list(head(intersection[order(intersection[2], decreasing = TRUE),],5)[,1:2], result_1, result_2))
}
```

This result is:

[image]
I want that the function will print the binomial test result for the five given marker genes (Exact Binomial Test 5 times provided the marker gene, instead of only showing one Exact Binomial Test). Could please anyone advise me what to fix to get the binomial results for the five given marker genes?

I have been trying to do some modification, such as result_2[i], ratio_spot[i], ratio_out_cluster[i] but does not work.

Update #2 Referring to the answer of @Sirius. I have modified it like this:

```
binom_test_2c = function(spot_id, cluster_id, marker_gene){
# Finding the cluster and marker gene in scRNA-seq dataset
cluster_id  = sample(as.data.frame(Idents(glioblastoma))[,1], 1)
marker = FindMarkers(glioblastoma, ident.1 = cluster_id)
marker = cbind(gene = rownames(marker), marker)
rownames(marker) = 1:nrow(marker) 

# Finding the cluster and the spot in spatial dataset
cluster = Idents(glio_spatial)
df_cluster = as.data.frame(cluster)
df_cluster = cbind(spot_id = rownames(df_cluster), df_cluster)
rownames(df_cluster) = 1:nrow(df_cluster)
df_cluster = df_cluster[df_cluster$cluster == sample(df_cluster[,ncol(df_cluster)],1),]
spot_id = sample(df_cluster[,1],1)
spatial_count = as.data.frame(glio_spatial@assays$Spatial@counts)
spatial_count = cbind(gene = rownames(spatial_count), spatial_count)
rownames(spatial_count) = 1:nrow(spatial_count) 
spatial_count = spatial_count[c("gene", spot_id)]
spatial_count = rename(spatial_count, "count" = spot_id)

#Finding the percentage of the marker gene expressed in the spot
# List of genes with not zero count at the chosen spot
gene_spot  = spatial_count[spatial_count$count != 0,]

#Finding gene intersection between scRNA-seq cluster and spot
intersection = inner_join(gene_spot, marker)

#Finding marker_gene sample
marker_gene = sample(head(intersection[order(intersection[2], decreasing = TRUE),],5)[,1],5)

l <- lapply( marker_gene, function(gene) {
    ratio_spot = gene_spot[which(gene_spot$gene == gene), ][,2]/sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])
    #Finding the percentage of the marker gene expressed outside the cluster
    all_cells_one_gene = glioblastoma@assays$RNA@counts[gene,]
    selected_cells_one_gene = all_cells_one_gene[cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]
    gene_count_out_cluster = glioblastoma@assays$RNA@counts[,cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]
    ratio_out_cluster = sum(selected_cells_one_gene)/sum(gene_count_out_cluster)
    result_1 = sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for scRNA-seq cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s.", marker_gene, cluster_id, spot_id)
    result_2 = binom.test(as.integer(ratio_spot*sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])), as.integer(sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])), as.integer(ratio_out_cluster))
    list( result_1=result_1, result_2=result_2)
}
result_1 <- sapply(l, function(el) el$result_1 )
result_2 <- sapply(l, function(el) el$result_2 )

return(
list(
    head(intersection[order(intersection[2], decreasing = TRUE),],5)[,1:2],
    result_1,
    result_2
))
}
```

Update #3 Referring to the answer of @Sirius. I got the result as below: I am trying to give the binom exact result dataframe column a name based on the marker gene to make it easy to read.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you consider the result, a p-value?

Comment: oh you mean just get those 5 model fits or what ever objects they are? ok no problem

Comment: Also , code needs to breath, it is way too condence to easily jump in and understand it (even for you 2 years down the line), adding lines and indentations and comments is always a good thing, (don't look at all the golfers)

Comment: Yes, I want to get those 5 model fits results (hopefully for more number of marker genes, but I am trying to get 5 first.)

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to make more sense of it:

```r
## change your for block rest of the function to this:

l <- lapply( marker_gene, function(gene) {
    ratio_spot = gene_spot[which(gene_spot$gene == gene), ][,2]/sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])
    #Finding the percentage of the marker gene expressed outside the cluster
    all_cells_one_gene = glioblastoma@assays$RNA@counts[gene,]
    selected_cells_one_gene = all_cells_one_gene[cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]
    gene_count_out_cluster = glioblastoma@assays$RNA@counts[,cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]
    ratio_out_cluster = sum(selected_cells_one_gene)/sum(gene_count_out_cluster)
    result_1 = sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for scRNA-seq cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s.", marker_gene, cluster_id, spot_id)
    result_2 = binom.test(as.integer(ratio_spot*sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])), as.integer(sum(gene_spot[,ncol(gene_spot)])), as.integer(ratio_out_cluster))
    list( result_1=result_1, result_2=result_2 )
}) # <----- I forgot this closing ')'

## fetch the result_1 strings
result_1 <- sapply( l, function(el) el$result_1 )
result_2 <- sapply( l, function(el) el$result_2 )

return(
    list(
        head(intersection[order(intersection[2], decreasing = TRUE),],5)[,1:2],
        result_1,
        result_2
    )
)
```

Use lapply to fetch stuff from each for loop, stuff it in a list and unpack it later. There are other ways, but if you come from not knowing how to pick up things from each iteration of a for loop, this is a good start.

Comment: I have modified it based on your suggestion. I think I got the idea of using lapply to apply it on the list of marker_gene and sapply to get the output as matrix. I am not sure about Fetching step, please explain it. Also, I replace the for i loop by your codes to see how it works, but it gets error: `Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:42:5: unexpected symbol 41:     } 42:     result_1         ^ Traceback:`

Comment: Updated, there should be a ')' after the '}' after the lapply block, see where I wrote "I forgot this closing..." in the code

Comment: It works now. However, I do not really understand how lapply works here. I think that lapply will give an output the same length as the input right? After running this, it gives  me a matrix 5x5 (each column shows the same thing), instead of 5x1 as the marker_gene dimension. Could you please explain? Also, the binom exact output is exactly like I wanted, but the p-value returns TRUE or FALSE instead of displaying the values of the p-value itself. Is it possible to show the p-value of the binomial test? My previous code showed one of the p-value is p-value<2.2e-16.